# Is it possible to reconstruct an order type from its initial segments?

Tags: order-theory, linear-orders, set-theory

Suppose

- $T$ is a [totally ordered set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) without a [maximal element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_element),
- $\tau$ is the [order type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_type) of $T$,
- $S$ is the set of order types of all proper [initial segments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_segment) (downward closed subsets) of $T$.

Is it always possible to unambiguously reconstruct $\tau$ from $S$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is **No**.

Let $\eta$ be the order type of $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\omega_1$ - the order type of the set of countable ordinals. The order types $\eta$ and $\eta \cdot \omega_1$ are different (because they have different cardinality), but the set of order types of all proper initial segments of some instances of $\eta$ and $\eta \cdot \omega_1$ is the same. Actually, as proved by [Joel David Hamkins](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1946/joel-david-hamkins), there are $2^{\aleph_1}$ distinct order types with this property: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174404/19661

Answer (score 14):

No. Take $\omega_1$, with each element replaced by a copy of $\mathbb Q$. Then $S$ will contain a single order type.  (The rest is left as an exercise.)

Comment: Well, not the single one: there are $\eta$ and $\eta+1$ (and maybe $\varnothing$ depending on the definition of "proper").